# Sensitive analysis with PYSWMM

Tags: python, jupyter

i am trying to conduct a sensitive analysis in a Porous Pavement in the LID module in the SWMM software.
To do this analysis i will need first to input my precipitation and PP parameters, then choose one parameter and make a number of simulations with my Porous Pavement changing the value of this parameter each simulation.I want to know if is possible to create some kind of loop were i could change the value of this parameter and retrive the output or save it in some table.

Thank you for the help!

I don´t have a lot of knowloge on programming soo i tried some simulation but i couldn´t make the loops changing the value of my parameter. also i am having trouble with getting the data at the same time as the precipitation falls.

Comment: I feel your question is quite general and it is not likely to receive a proper answer. You might get help from people around you. Or you could start with the documentation of the software you use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found some documentation, i having a hard time with it but i am trying to make it. Anyway it would be good to find someone who already work with this before. thanks for your time !